# Forwarding data between NICs on Raspberry PI

Tags: networking, ethernet

So I've recently acquired a second ethernet card for my raspberry PI, and I want to be able to plug my laptop into eth1, and my router into eth0 and have the PI forward the packets between my laptop and my router. I've come across tutorials on how to set the PI up as a router in this configuration, but that involves the laptop getting an IP address from the PI. What I'm looking for is for the PI to forward DHCP requests from the laptop to the router so that it gets it's IP address from the router rather than the PI, but the PI has a record of the communication. Essentially what it will eventually do is act as wireshark for network devices that can't run wireshark :) Does anyone know if this is possible or know of any good tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're asking about is bridging two interfaces.

Shamelessly plagiarised from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=100053&p=694403):

```
apt-get install bridge-utils
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 wlan0 wlan1
ifup br0
```

See also the [Debian documentation for `bridge-utils`](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections).